# get form data of radio buttons with different names

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

my php page contains a form with multiple radio buttons with different names as shown below:

```
for( $i=1; $i<=$unknownNumber; $i++ ){

echo("<input type=\"radio\" name=\""."radio".$i."\" value=\"cercle\" onchange=\"submit(this.form)\" checked >");
echo("<input type=\"radio\" name=\""."radio".$i."\" value=\"rectangle\"  onchange=\"submit(this.form)\" >");
echo("<input type=\"radio\" name=\""."radio".$i."\" value=\"triangle\"   onchange=\"submit(this.form)\" >");

}
```

How can i get the form data via `$_POST[" ? "]` from a process php page?

I dont know what i should write into the quote of `$_POST["..."]` , because the names of radio buttons are different.

A friend of mine advice me to get these Data just by doing as below,

```
foreach ($_POST as $answer) {


}
```

I get them with this method, but i am blocked to use ajax with it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myForm').on('submit', function() {

        var radio = $('#....').val(); // I dont know which name i should use here

        $.post( "process.php", { radio: ? }, function(data){ 

            alert('Good');

        });

        return false; 
    });

});
```

Comment: Radios are designed to share the same name to have a choice between values.

Comment: Have you tried this? `var radio= $('input[type=radio]:checked').val();`

Comment: @Tyr I want to have many groups of 3 radio buttons.

Comment: Then use $('#myForm').serialize() to post all fields of the form.

Comment: @Tyr When i use serialize, the POST data is : radio1=cercle&radio2=rectangle&radio3=triangle. But i don t know how to decode it in order to get an associative array like this: $myArray = array("radio1"=>"cercle", "radio2"=>"rectangle", "radio3"=>"triangle");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code. In php removed onclick event

```
for( $i=1; $i<=$unknownNumber; $i++ ){

   echo("<input type=\"radio\" name=\""."radio".$i."\" value=\"cercle\" checked>");
   echo("<input type=\"radio\" name=\""."radio".$i."\" value=\"rectangle\">");
   echo("<input type=\"radio\" name=\""."radio".$i."\" value=\"triangle\">");
}
```

And JS modified to this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[name^="radio"]').on('click', function() {
        $.post( "process.php", $("#myForm").serialize(), function(data){
            alert('Good');
        });
    });
});
```

After each click on radio to your PHP script "process.php" will be sent full form. For exapmle here is POST data :

> radio1:triangle
>
> radio2:cercle
>
> radio3:triangle

According to this request you will have

```
$_POST["radio1"]='triangle'; 
$_POST["radio2"]='cercle';
$_POST["radio3"]='triangle';
```

Update!!!!

In chrome developer tools you can see smth like this [image: In chrome developer tools you can see smth like this]

Here is my process.php

```
$myArray = $_POST;
var_dump($myArray);
```

[image: this code outputs]

Comment: the POST data is : radio1=triangle&radio2=cercle&radio3=triangle. But i don t know how to decode it in order to get an associative array like this: $myArray = array("radio1"=>"triangle", "radio2"=>"cercle", "radio3"=>"triangle");

Comment: make var_dump($_POST) andd see the result; 

you had to use $myArray=$_POST in your script